# NReco PdfGenerator disable selection

Tags: c#, nreco

I want to disable selection, just like an image, even if contain text.

I know PDF contain layers, but i dont find where to remove the text layer.

Thanks.

```
        var htmlToPdf = new NReco.PdfGenerator.HtmlToPdfConverter();
        htmlToPdf.Size = NReco.PdfGenerator.PageSize.Letter;

        htmlToPdf.Margins = new NReco.PdfGenerator.PageMargins()
        {
            Bottom = 0,
            Top = 0,
            Left = 0,
            Right = 0
        };
        string ID = "Test";
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("inline;FileName=\"{0}.pdf\"", ID));

        htmlToPdf.GeneratePdfFromFile("Page.aspx", null, Response.OutputStream);

        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PdfGenerator internally uses wkhtmltopdf and it renders text content as text blocks and they are selectable by default; this behavior cannot be changed. If you want to guarantee that text cannot be selected it should be rendered as image (= you can render HTML to image first, and then produce PDF that contains this image).

Another alternative is encryption of produced PDF with iTextSharp, see answer for [Lock PDF against editing using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8419649/lock-pdf-against-editing-using-itextsharp)
- with only PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING option (LGPL version 4.1.6 of iTextSharp can be used for this purpose).